# HI have just started learning MYSQL any suggestions to speed it up.... and i am curious why this code is not working.procedure created but not work

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

```
DELIMITER $$
USE DB_1$$
create procedure SHOWTAB(in tab varchar(255) )
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM tab ;
END$$
DELIMITER ;


CALL SHOWTAB(emp);
```

emp IS TABLE MY DATABASE

Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'emp' in 'field list'

Comment: stored procedures are an advanced feature; if you are just learning mysql, I'd focus on other things for a long while first.

Comment: I did cover them but now I wanted to learn advanced-level SQL... I would appreciate if you guide me for this in little further details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Table and column names can't be variables. If you want to specify the table name dynamicaly, you have to construct the SQL dynamically.

```
DELIMITER $$
USE DB_1$$
create procedure SHOWTAB(in tab varchar(255) )
BEGIN
    SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM `', tab, '`');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

And you need to quote the name `emp` to make it a string when calling the procedure.

```
CALL SHOWTAB('emp');
```